# Reply to an email to the person whose name is in parentheses

Tags: email, email-etiquette

I got an email for a interviewing and the first person CC'ed someone like this; "I have copied in FirstName LastName (NameHere) who is the Hiring Manager"

My question is how can respond my email and which name I should use?

Thanks

Comment: I appreciate you accepting my answer, but it's probably best to wait a day or two before accepting, in case a better answer is posted. (However, you can always change which answer you accept later.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes you are right I can change this later but the question was not hard, just wanted to clarify which is the official way to responds a person who also write a name in parentheses. Your answer make sense

Comment: This is also a common notation for people who have changed their name recently, e.g. because they got married. The name in parentheses would be the old name, so people who had prior contact with that person can make the connection.

Comment: What exactly is in the place of "NameHere"?  A first name?  A last name?  Both?  Something ambiguous?  Is it a name from a different culture than FirstName LastName?

Comment: what is your country? type of workplace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your response will have any material information that might be of interest to the hiring manager, you should "reply all" to ensure both your correspondents receive it. If it's going to be something trivial, like a "thank you" or a confirmation for the interview date, it's probably better to respond to the originator only.

As for the hiring manager's name, if I needed to address the person, I would use "FirstName" and/or "LastName", as appropriate for the local culture, until and if the moment comes you know them better. The manager will likely be present at the interview and might tell you "please call me NameHere", which you then should do.

Comment: You may want to change that "use firstname" to something like "use the first or lastname as appropriate in your culture". Calling my future boss by their first name without invitation to do so would be quite insulting where I live.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing this particular case, a person who  writes their name in parentheses usually has a given name which is difficult for people in the locale to say.  This tends to be most common when Asian people (with the notable exception of Japan) deal with people from North America, because it is  very difficult for native English speakers  to say many Chinese, Korean, or various other Asian names properly.  Better to just use a different name, than to have your name constantly and  perpetually butchered by people  who don't know your language, is the theory.

In general, people who have a "local" name will more commonly use that one when dealing with people not  of their own nationality who can't say their name properly.  That said, it's not rude or whatever to use their  given name; it's also not rude to use their local name, that's  why they've given you the choice.

My thoughts on the matter is you should use whichever name you would use if you were speaking in person.  If you think you could accurately and comfortably pronounce their given name in a face to face conversation, then use that one; if not, then use the other one.  If nothing else, it builds a routine; then,  when/if this person meets  you face to face, you won't all of a sudden call them by a different name than you've been calling them  all along.  I don't have this issue personally, but  if I did, I  would imagine  it  to be an awkward scenario if it were to happen.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't put anyone's name in there. Just address it as:

> Thank you! See you `<time of booked interview>`.
>
> Regards,
> `<your name>`

Comment: This answer isn't particularly  helpful.  It solves this one instance, but eventually OP is  going to talk to this person (they are the hiring manager, after all, it's inevitable),  and they're  going to have to say their name.  OP can't dance around the issue forever.